# Copying a circular buffer to a larger buffer while preserving contents and modulus indices

Tags: algorithm, scala, circular-buffer

I am keeping an efficient circular buffer `buf` as an array and two total read and write counts `bufRead` and `bufWrite` such that `bufRead % buf.length` and `bufWrite % buf.length` are correct indices into buffer for current operations.

Now I might need to "grow" the array at some point because the buffer size expands. So I want to replace `buf` with a new, larger array, but preserve all the previous contents of the buffer **while preserving the above modulus properties**. So if at `bufRead % buf.length` in the old buffer we find element *X*, then I want this element *X* to be found again at the same index `bufRead % buf.length` after `buf` has been updated.

Example:

```
trait Algorithm {
  var buf: Array[Double]
  var bufRead : Long  // this won't be needed in `resize`
  var bufWrite: Long  // this won't be needed in `resize`

  def resize(newLength: Int): Unit = {
    val newBuf = new Array[Double](newLength)
    ???
    buf = newBuf
  }
}
```

A test procedure:

```
def test(in: Algorithm): Unit = {
  import in._
  import math.{min, random}
  val avail  = buf.length // (bufWrite - bufRead).toInt
  val data0  = Array.fill(avail)(random)
  val off0   = (bufRead % buf.length).toInt
  val chunk0 = min(avail, buf.length - off0)  
  val off1   = (off0 + chunk0) % buf.length
  val chunk1 = avail - chunk0

  System.arraycopy(data0, 0     , buf, off0, chunk0)
  System.arraycopy(data0, chunk0, buf, off1, chunk1)

  resize(avail * 2)  // arbitrary growth

  val data1  = new Array[Double](avail)
  val off2   = (bufRead % buf.length).toInt
  val chunk2 = min(avail, buf.length - off2)
  val off3   = (off2 + chunk2) % buf.length
  val chunk3 = avail - chunk2
  System.arraycopy(buf, off2, data1, 0     , chunk2)
  System.arraycopy(buf, off3, data1, chunk2, chunk3)

  assert(data0 sameElements data1)
}
```

Comment: You want `a % b = a % c`, where `b < c`. Doesn't seem possible to me. Have you considered creating more buffers of same size instead of enlarging the current buffer? You would of course need to do some housekeeping to figure out which buffer things got pushed into, but at least you would be able to keep your modulus property. Another option is to increase the number of items that can be held in a single buffer location, but again, different to what you want...

Comment: @wookie919 No! The indices may change due to the update, but the _contents_ at indices thus calculated before and after the update must remain the same. So, the contents to preserve is found at `(bufRead until (bufRead + oldLength)) % buf.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible approaches:

- re-ordering the contents so they fit into the new modulus

  ```
  for (i <- bufRead until bufWrite) {
      newBuf(i % newBuf.length) = buf(i % buf.length)
  }
  ```
- resetting `read` and `write` pointers to fit to the new array

  ```
  var j = 0
  for (i <- bufRead until bufWrite) {
      newBuf(j) = buf(i % buf.length)
      j += 1
  }
  bufWrite -= bufRead
  bufRead = 0
  ```

I'm not sure whether you want to keep track of the number of all elements the buffer has ever stored, if yes then the second approach doesn't work of course. The first approach, re-ordering, shouldn't be too much of a hazzle as you need to copy the contents from the old into the new array anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the first version would actually work. Changing the pointers does not work in my case because they track total frames transferred which would become invalid after modifying them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following is correct:

```
class Impl(size0: Int) extends Algorithm {
  var buf = new Array[Double](size0)
  var bufRead  = 0L
  var bufWrite = 0L   // unused here

  override def resize(newLength: Int): Unit = {
    import math.{min, max}
    val newBuf    = new Array[Double](newLength)
    val oldLength = buf.length
    val off0      = (bufRead % oldLength).toInt
    val off1      = (bufRead % newLength).toInt
    val chunk0    = min(oldLength - off0, newLength - off1)
    System.arraycopy(buf, off0, newBuf, off1, chunk0)
    val off2      = (off0 + chunk0) % oldLength
    val off3      = (off1 + chunk0) % newLength
    val chunk1    = min(oldLength - max(chunk0, off2), newLength - off3)
    System.arraycopy(buf, off2, newBuf, off3, chunk1)
    val off4      = (off2 + chunk1) % oldLength
    val off5      = (off3 + chunk1) % newLength
    val chunk2    = oldLength - (chunk0 + chunk1)
    System.arraycopy(buf, off4, newBuf, off5, chunk2)
    buf = newBuf
  }
}
```

Test:

```
for (r <- 0 until 200) {
  val a = new Impl(100)
  a.bufRead = r   // test all possible offsets
  test(a)
}
```